# Hazelcast-client configuration on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hazelcast

My question regards hazelcast-client configuration.
From what I understand, when configured properly the client is supposed to fetch hazelcast server nodes IPs automatically from the AWS api , the problem is doesn't even try connect.

Here's some log I found.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: []
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport.connectToCluster(ClusterListenerSupport.java:178)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientClusterServiceImpl.start(ClientClusterServiceImpl.java:189)
```

also here's client conifig

```
<bean id="hazelcastInstance" class="com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient"  factory-method="newHazelcastClient">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig">
                <property name="groupConfig">
                    <bean class="com.hazelcast.config.GroupConfig">
                        <property name="name" value="dev"/>
                    </bean>
                    </property>

                     <property name="properties">
                       <props>
                       <prop key="hazelcast.icmp.enabled">true</prop>
                       </props>
                     </property>
                <property name="networkConfig">
                    <bean class="com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientNetworkConfig">

                    <property name="awsConfig">
                            <bean class="com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientAwsConfig">
                                <property name="insideAws" value="true" />
                                <property name="enabled" value="${hazelcast.aws.enabled:false}" />
                                <property name="region" value="${hazelcast.aws.region:set-me}" />
                                <property name="accessKey"value="key" />

                                <property name="secretKey" value="secret"/>


                                <property name="hostHeader" value="ec2.amazonaws.com"/>
                                <property name="iamRole" value="${hazelcast.aws.iam.role:#{null}}"/>
                                <!-- <property name="securityGroupName" value="${hazelcast.aws.securityGroupName:#{null}}" /> -->
                                <property name="tagKey" value="${hazelcast.aws.tagKey:hazelcast-cluster}" />
                                <property name="tagValue" value="${hazelcast.aws.tagValue:#{null}}" />
                                <property name="connectionTimeoutSeconds" value="${hazelcast.aws.connectionTimeout:15}" />

                            </bean>
                        </property> 
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>

        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

also tried to force server ip, that works.  I need the client to discover server ips automatically. any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the discovery plugin mechanism if you want the client to discover clusters on AWS (or any other cloud). The old AWS discovery was for members only.

Please see https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws